# Maybe the dream "is telling" you the future when you "are sleeping" - When we make a general statement, can we use the present continuous tense?

Tags: present-continuous

When we make a general statement (something habitual, or something regularly occurring), can we use the present continuous tense?

**Example 1**

> A: I have been seeing dreams recently.

> B: Maybe the dream **is telling** you the future when you **are sleeping**.

**Example 2**

> A: I have been going to the gym and have lost some weight.

> B: Maybe your body burns lots of calories when you **are doing** exercises.

Comment: We _have_ dreams rather than _see_ them, but the continuous tense is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use the present continuous tense.
 Present simple works just as well, as shown here:

> Maybe the dream **tells** you the future when you **sleep**.

> Maybe your body burns lots of calories when you **do** exercises.